ModuleNotFoundError in Python Spyder despite being installed with Conda
I am using Anaconda and Spyder IDE. I have installed seaborn, sklearn and statsmodels in conda via command prompt command (using conda install -c conda-forge seaborn  )
The installation in conda seems succesful. However when I try to actually import these packages in Spyder, using import seaborn as sns, I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'. The same for sklearn and statsmodels.
I have previously installed Numpy and Pandas, and they work fine.
I have no idea what to do. I have googled here similar posts, tried shutting down and restarting Spyder, but I still get the same error. Please help.
Edit: as I recall I actually installed sklearn already few months ago via conda, and then the import command seemed to work fine. But when I try it now, I get the error described above as well as for seaborn and statsmodels. So I really don't understand what is going on.
I am guessing it might be something to do with where Anaconda installs the package? And the path / environment? But I don't know how to go about finding out and rectifying these things.

Have you ever installed Python before installing Anaconda? Once, I had Python 3.8 and 3.10 simultaneously and that can cause problems.

I am not sure. I am working on a work laptop for which a lot of software (like RStudio ) is sitting on a server somewhere remotely to the best of my understanding.  @ManuelVeiga

In that case I would try to contact with the server host to see if there are several versions of it. Maybe in programs, you need to access to the "AppData" folder (With admin permission in your laptop) and from there you can check.
Another option is to uninstall seaborn and, as Python should be in your computer, you install it from the cmd, and then "pip install seaborn"

How do I check if conda is sitting remotely or on my laptop independently? Do I need to contact host for this as well? Sorry for asking, no clue about tech stuff. Also, isn't pip incompatible with conda install? I heard that using pip with conda breaks it @ManuelVeiga

You need to allow admin permissions on your computer to access the folder AppData. If the computer was given from a company to you probably you don´t have host permissions. If you purchase it you can allow then.

See my comment on this question which sounds like a similar issue. You can have multiple Python installations on the same computer and it sounds like Spyder is not using the same one that you installed the new modules for. The Spyder documentation FAQs are also useful.
